# how to create navbar from with text and icon?

Tags: html, css, search, header, navbar

how to create a **navbar** same as **stack overflow** navbar with *search* form *icon*.
i use it but cant find a way.

````
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search here..">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </form>```
````

Answer (score 0):

You use DIV's to contain each group of code and arrange them using CSS.  I changed the div class form-group to contain the entire form in one container.  And you can use the class topnav to contain the images or text you want next to the search bar.  Just a little CSS and your on your way!

```
<div class="topnav">
  <a>Stack Overflow</a>
  <div class="form-group">
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search here..">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```